# How to show a notification every hour in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

As a newbie to android, am developing a simple application. The app requires a notification to be displayed every hour which carries a message "Hey got a message". Your guidance on how to implement with a code help would be appreciated. Apologies for the basic question.

Comment: Using work manager will be suitable for periodic tasks.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: WorkManager is suitable for _deferrable_ periodic tasks.  A notification that needs to be shown every hour is not deferrable, as it may happen unpredictably later.